# Skaffold debug is missing JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with Helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, google-cloud-code

If I understand the documentation here correctly...

[Skaffold Debug](https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/debug/#java-and-other-jvm-languages)

If I try to run K8s Project with 'skaffold debug' or with IntelliJ 'Develop on Kubernetes' and Debug, skaffold must insert in my k8s deployment/service files extra port for jdwp and Environment Variable with JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Which is not happening for me.

I am using a Helm Chart to deploy my k8s artifacts and I don't see anywhere that these things are configured (as it also mentioned here [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2912)).

If I configure my deployment\service yamls manually, to insert port 5005 for jdwp and environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS for jdwp and port forward 5005 then I can remotely attach to process and debug, but skaffold is not able to manage it by itself (It is not even trying, I see no JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in my logs).

May be, it does not understand that I am running a JVM project or may be, while I created with my Helm Project with 'helm create' and there are several yaml files (configmap.yaml, deployment.yaml, hpa.yaml, ingress.yaml, service.yaml, serviceaccount.yaml) it is not able to find correct file to manipulate.

If I also understand correctly, the deployment/pod that would be debugged must have following annotations:

[Annotations](https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/debug/#workload-annotations)

> debug.cloud.google.com/config

which are missing completely, only thing I see on deployment is the following -

```
ide: idea
ideVersion: 2021.1.1.0.0
ijPluginVersion: unknown
skaffold.dev/run-id: d2420cca-f212-4349-b078-41f36ed51bd5
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Actually, deployment functioning correctly and my Pod reports Ok for Readyness check but no debugging starting from skaffold/intellij.

Comment: Are you deploying an image that was built by Skaffold?  `debug` only marks up built images to avoid affecting system- or infrastructure-level containers like sidecars etc.

Comment: And what base image are you using?  (I'll be adding a _Troubleshooting_ section to the Skaffold debug docs.)

Comment: Yes, image is build via Skaffold with JiB and my base image is 'adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u282-b08-slim'

Comment: So that image has a `JAVA_VERSION` environment variable defined, which should be sufficient to cause the JVM recognizer. Could you please run `skaffold debug -v debug` to enable verbose logging and attach the logs here?

Comment: Here is the skaffold debug logs https://www.mediafire.com/file/cbfy2g4bjc2yukm/skaffold.debug/file

Comment: Thanks for that log.  I can see the Skaffold is correctly calling `helm install --post-renderer ...\skaffold.exe` (with other arguments).  But the environment reported doesn't include some key environment variables like `SKAFFOLD_CMDLINE` and `SKAFFOLD_FILENAME`.  Would it be possible to open a new issue on at https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/new with your source bundle? (eliding any personal information)

Comment: Ok I will try to anonymise the Project but it might take little bit of time

Comment: I followed your advice and created an Issue at https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some mismatches between the @posthumecaver's Helm chart and the `skaffold.yaml` that prevented Skaffold from configuring the image.  I'll summarize the findings here for the benefit of those who stumble across this post.

@posthumecaver is using Skaffold's Helm support.  This requires that the `skaffold.yaml` and the Helm chart use a common key for referencing the image.  There are three approaches used in Helm for referencing images:

#### Fully-Qualified Name (default)

Skaffold will configure Helm setting a key to the fully-tagged image reference.

The `skaffold.yaml` setup:

```
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: my-chart
        chartPath: helm
        artifactOverrides:
          img: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
```

The chart template:

```
image: "{{.Values.img}}"
```

The `values.yaml` (note that Skaffold overrides this value):

```
img: gcr.io/other-project/other-image:latest
```

Skaffold will invoke

```
helm install <chart> <chart-path> --set-string img=gcr.io/my-project/my-image:generatedTag@sha256:digest
```

#### Split Repository and Tag

Skaffold can be configured to provide Helm with a separate repository and tag.  The key used in the `artifactOverrides` is used as base portion producing two keys `{key}.repository` and `{key}.tag`.

The `skaffold.yaml` setup:

```
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: my-chart
        chartPath: helm
        artifactOverrides:
          img: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
        imageStrategy:
          helm: {}
```

The chart template:

```
image: "{{.Values.img.repository}}:{{.Values.img.tag}}"
```

The `values.yaml` (note that Skaffold overrides these value):

```
img:
  repository: gcr.io/other-project/other-image
  tag: latest
```

Skaffold will invoke

```
helm install <chart> <chart-path> --set-string img.repository=gcr.io/my-project/my-image,img.tag=generatedTag@sha256:digest
```

#### Split Registry, Repository, and Tag

Skaffold can also be configured to provide Helm with a separate repository and tag.  The key used in the `artifactOverrides` is used as base portion producing three keys: `{key}.registry`, `{key}.repository`, and `{key}.tag`.

The `skaffold.yaml` setup:

```
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: my-chart
        chartPath: helm
        artifactOverrides:
          img: gcr.io/my-project/my-image
        imageStrategy:
          helm:
            explicitRegistry: true
```

The chart template:

```
image: "{{.Values.img.registry}}/{{.Values.img.repository}}:{{.Values.img.tag}}"
```

The `values.yaml` (note that Skaffold overrides these value):

```
img:
  registry: gcr.io
  repository: other-project/other-image
  tag: latest
```

Skaffold will invoke

```
helm install <chart> <chart-path> --set-string img.registry=gcr.io,img.repository=my-project/my-image,img.tag=generatedTag@sha256:digest
```

Comment: First of all thx for the tip, when I made the changes you mentioned in my PoC project in the ticket, it works. Unfortunately my real life project is little bit different then the PoC. It is a part of an multi module Helm Project, the project that I want to debug, reference a configmap from another helm chart. So when I try to install the complete Helm chart and try to debug sub Helm Chart, skaffold again does not manage to manipulate JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, I will create a variation of the PoC which simulates this situation, can you please check that and tell me anything can be done for it

Comment: And additionally, I am using the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to set "-Xms512M -Xmx512M" unfornutaley when skaffold replaces the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=n,quiet=y" it completely ignores the memory settings and overwrites those. Is it possible that it will append the previous values to debug values?